# Define next object after swipe in tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos, tvos10

I am new to tvOS and I have very simple app:

1) There is UISegmentedControl in top of screen that takes about 80% of screen width.

2) Right under UISegmentedControl I have UITableView and UIView with detailed information for each of cells (when user select them) - they both have 50% width of UISegmentedControl

After user have selected first or second item in SegmentedControl he can get to tableView with swiping down (because tableView is right under this two segments). But if user selects last segment and tries to swipe down in order to get to tableview - nothing happens. What can be done with it?